# How to make a after insert trigger to another table work in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have been trying to write a trigger function that updates the rows in the child table when the parent is changed for a while now. I have read Trigger procedure documentation but what I have tried that does not work any action... here what i wrote :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION follow_up_aft_ins0()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    declare
        count_fu integer;
    BEGIN
        select into count_fu count(fu.prospek_id) from pros_fu fu 
        where fu.prospek_id = new.prospek_id and (fu.hasil_fu='Unreachable');

        if (count_fu >=3 ) then 
            update pros p set status = 'Trash' where p.prospek_id = new.prospek_id; 
        end if;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION follow_up_aft_ins0()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Your Select statement order is incorrect. The syntax for select ALWAYS has the select list immediately after the keyword. The INTO clause follows in it is needed. So try: *select  count(fu.prospek_id) into count_fu from ...*

Comment: i follow your instruction but still not work, i will be appreciate when u come to help

Comment: saying it did not work is totally and completely useless.  What **exactly** did you run, and what **exactly** was the result. If results what was wrong, If an error what is the complete error.